# Import error with nag4py: "cannot import name INIT_FAIL"

Tags: python, python-2.7, eigenvalue

I have a script to compute eigenvalues and vectors without balancing, which I used almost daily for years, that requires nag4py. The code is in this blog: http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=5303 for which there is an associated SO post ([How to use eig with the nobalance option as in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625532/how-to-use-eig-with-the-nobalance-option-as-in-matlab)).

Yesterday I upgraded nag4py and now I run into the following error when running the same script that has been working for years:

> from nag4py.util import
>   Nag_RowMajor,Nag_NoBalancing,Nag_NotLeftVecs,Nag_RightVecs,Nag_RCondEigVecs,Integer,NagError,INIT_FAIL
>
> ImportError: cannot import name INIT_FAIL

In the meantime I have solved the problem by importing octave which uses the no balancing option by default. But I would like to resolve the issue with nag4py.

I have tested the NAG licence and it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

The release version of the nag4py package uses 'quiet_fail' and 'noisy_fail', which are documented in the embedded doc:

> Error or warning cases detected by the NAG C Library are handled
>   in nag4py using a similar NagError mechanism as in the Library
>   itself. The nag4py util module provides two convenience functions
>   ('quiet_fail' and 'noisy_fail') to create a NagError instance with
>   printing of messages disabled or enabled, respectively.

Here's the change:

```
Index: nag4py/util.py
===================================================================
--- nag4py/util.py  (revision 104707)
+++ nag4py/util.py  (revision 104708)
@@ -4736,14 +4736,20 @@
     return _arg


-def INIT_FAIL(fail):
+def quiet_fail():
+    "Returns a NagError instance with printing disabled."
+    fail = NagError()
     fail.eprint = Nag_FALSE
+    return fail

-def SET_FAIL(fail):
+def noisy_fail():
+    "Returns a NagError instance with printing enabled."
+    fail = NagError()
     fail.eprint = Nag_TRUE
+    return fail

-__all__.append("INIT_FAIL")
-__all__.append("SET_FAIL")
+__all__.append("quiet_fail")
+__all__.append("noisy_fail")

 def get_input_func():
     from sys import version_info
```